# ELK logs with kibana

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Im new into big data, and I have some difficulties with importing a json file to kibana, and I don't know how to map json files, so if you could help me I would be really grateful, here is the json file

```
    {"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"Positivity_score":55.17999999,"Negativity_score":35.12,"Average_Positivity":0.8621874999999999,"Average_Negativity":0.54875}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"Positivity_score":134.71999999999997,"Negativity_score":90.08000000000017,"Average_Positivity":0.8419999999999999,
"Average_Negativity":0.5701265822784821}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"Positivity_score":44.800000000000004,"Negativity_score":28.799999999999986,"Average_Positivity":0.7344262295081968,
"Average_Negativity":0.47999999999999976}
```

and here is the log i wrote with is probably wrong

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/sentimentresult -d '
{
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "_id" : {"type": "integer","index":"not_analyzed"},
    "Positivity_score" : { "type" : "double" },
    "Negativity_score" : { "type" : "double" },
    "Average_Positivity" : { "type" : "double"},
    "Average_Positivity" : { "type" : "double"}
   }
  }
 }
}
';
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating your index with the above default mapping, you can simply post your JSON file to the [`_bulk` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/sentimentresult/sentiment/_bulk -d '
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"Positivity_score":55.17999999,"Negativity_score":35.12,"Average_Positivity":0.8621874999999999,"Average_Negativity":0.54875}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"Positivity_score":134.71999999999997,"Negativity_score":90.08000000000017,"Average_Positivity":0.8419999999999999, "Average_Negativity":0.5701265822784821}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"Positivity_score":44.800000000000004,"Negativity_score":28.799999999999986,"Average_Positivity":0.7344262295081968, "Average_Negativity":0.47999999999999976}
'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I tried it but it still gives me errors, I tried it without creating a son file and putting the path in the command and it gives me the

   {"error":"ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]","status":400}
and I tried it like you gave it to me, and still gives me an error

{"took":37,"errors":false,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"sentimentresult","_type":"sentiment","_id":"1","_version":2,"st

Comment: The response you get is **not an error** (i.e. `"errors":false`), you should now have 3 documents in your `sentimentresult` index.

Comment: I can see the sentimentresult in kibana but there are no data in there, it's just empty

Comment: According to the result you got, there should be data in there. What do you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/sentimentresult/_search`?